# Is it possible to detect all calls of viewDidAppear in one spot?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to trigger some analytics code every time a user in my iOS app moves to a new screen.

Is there a way to detect every call to `viewDidAppear`, or do I need to implement this in every `ViewController` ?

Comment: how about creating a subset of `UIViewController` with a customised `–viewDidAppear:` method? then you can inherit all of your view controllers from that class – that is a _miracle_ of OOP, huh?

Comment: @holex I had considered this, but the existing code is pretty messy so I wanted to consider all options before moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lots of the analytics suppliers frameworks offer this feature. Generally they're implemented with swizzling, so they replace the `UIViewController` implementation to capture the analytics and then call the stock implementation. As all your view controllers should call `super` then their code will be run.

It's also possible that you could create a superclass for all your view controllers but this is harder to fit into most apps.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to one of my apps with google analytics. At that time I had to subclass my controllers from `GAITrackedViewController`.  That pretty much did it. I added the `self.screenName = @"some screen name";` on `viewDidAppear` method just to know where the user was on my GA Dashboard.
It was explained on the GA docs, so it won't be hard to find.